# How to copy files and rename on the fly when source filename contains embedded spaces

Tags: command-line, scp

I am trying to copy and rename image files from one directory into another directory.

The files I want to copy have blank spaces embedded in their file names, and I want to replace part of the file name with the date that the image was taken.

Below is an example of the file names and the command that I have been using, along with an example of the error messages that I have been seeing.

For example, I would like to copy the "2008_08_17_Transfer 001.jpg" file from the source directory and rename it to "20090314001.jpg" in the target directory and so forth, for each file in the source directory that starts with "2008_08_17_Transfer ".

Here is what I tried and the error messages I see:

```
$ ls -l
total 241968
-rw------- 1 stephen stephen  1347770 Mar 14  2009 2008_08_17_Transfer 001.jpg
-rw------- 1 stephen stephen  1077919 Mar 14  2009 2008_08_17_Transfer 002.jpg
-rw------- 1 stephen stephen  1359947 Mar 14  2009 2008_08_17_Transfer 003.jpg
-rw------- 1 stephen stephen  1309175 Mar 14  2009 2008_08_17_Transfer 004.jpg
-rw------- 1 stephen stephen  1404298 Mar 14  2009 2008_08_17_Transfer 005.jpg
...

for i in *.jpg ; do scp -p "$i" /media/stephen/WDMyBook1_ext4/PicturesRenamedByDateTaken/2009/20090314/20090314`echo "$i" ` ; done

001.jpg: No such file or directory
002.jpg: No such file or directory
003.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *.jpg ; do 
  cp -p "$i" "/media/stephen/WDMyBook1_ext4/PicturesRenamedByDateTaken/2009/20090314/20090314${i##* }"
done
```

The shell parameter expansion `${i##* }` removes the longest prefix ending in a space (i.e. everything up to and including the space before the `00n.jpg` numeric suffix). There is no need to use `echo`.

I'm assuming this is a local copy so you don't need `scp`.

Note: if you want to *derive* the `20090314` programmatically from the directory name, that's doable - but obviously complicates things a little.

Comment: This did EXACTLY what I wanted to do.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just put quotes around the file name, like this

```
for i in *.jpg ; do scp -p "$i" "/media/stephen/WDMyBook1_ext4/PicturesRenamedByDateTaken/2009/20090314/20090314`echo "$i" `" ; done
```

Comment: This copied the files for me and added the date stamp on the front of the file name, but it also copied the entire file name, which is not what I wanted in this case.  I do have a use for doing it this way, however, on some of my other directories, so this solution will also be useful to me.  Thank you so very much.